# Changing bash prompt temporarily by own script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, prompt

I wanted to write a tiny shell script that shortens the commmand prompt when it gets too long. Setting the PS1 variable in bash works fine. When I try the same command directly in a script and run it, nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/bash

PS1='\u:\W\$ '
```

I tried `eval "PS1='\u:\W\$ '"` , `export PS1='\u:\W\$ '` and `exec PS1='\u:\W\$ '` without any result.

How can I achieve the same result as a direct input in the bash?

Thank you in advance

Comment: BTW, you might consider using a shell function rather than a script for this.

Comment: That means adding a function to ~/.profile or ~/bashrc?

Comment: `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.profile` -- the bashrc is executed for every interactive shell, the profile only for login shells (except for in some operating systems that try to be "easier" for users by erasing the difference, but it's bad form to count on being on one of those), and regular functions aren't inherited by child processes, so (unlike environment variables, which are appropriate for `~/.profile`) you won't get them everywhere you need them unless they're in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: ...you could also call your function from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, and then it'll be invoked automatically (if it's actually inspecting terminal width and deciding which prompt to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in UNIX, a process can only change variables for itself and its children -- not its parent ("its parent" being the process that invoked it).

You need to *source* a script, not execute it, for it to be able to effect your interactive shell's variables. This executes all commands inside the script inside your current shell, not a new shell started as a child process (whose variables' values are thrown away on exit).

```
# in bash
source yourscript

# or in POSIX sh
. yourscript # mind the space!
```

In this usage, the shebang does nothing; similarly, the `+x` permission isn't needed either. It's also typical to name scripts intended to be sourced rather than executed with an extension mapping to the shell they're intended to be used by (`yourscript.bash` for bash, `yourscript.sh` for a script which can be sourced by any POSIX shell), whereas scripts intended to be executed rather than sourced should have no extension.